# How to reorder the content of the single post?

Tags: author, single

I installed the "Related Posts" plugin and use

```
<?php the_content(''); ?>
```

to show my single post in single.php. When I want to add the author's name after the post, I use

```
<?php the_content(''); ?>
<?php the_author(); ?>
```

but the author's name is showing after the related posts, which I don't want. I want the author's name after the last word in this post. Is there a way to do this, or have an array of `the_content` and reorder the inner content? Here is my code:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="single_post_content">
        <div class="single_post_img">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title();?>">  <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a> 
        </div>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <p>بقلم :  <?php the_author(); ?></p>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php comments_template('',true); ?>
```

Even if I use `add_filter` in functions.php, or try to combine them with `echo`, it does the same thing.

Comment: Most probably that plugin hooks to `the_content` filter. I don't you write your own related posts function and add it where needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in functions.php

```
function author_after_content($content) {     

if ( is_singular('post') ) {

    $content .= "<p>بقلم :  " . the_author() . "</p>";
}
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'author_after_content', 20);
```

Comment: this code show the name before the post

Comment: This is weird. it works with just a `<p> بقلم : </p>`, so the_author is probably the problem.

Comment: so.... is there a way to have an array of "the_content" ?? or something to see every detail in "the_content"

Comment: Use get_the_author instead of the_author in that function.

Comment: I was install a "Social Share Boost" and "WordPress Related Posts" plugins, and my real problem is the name of the author is shown after the buttons and links of this plugins  not directly after the post text

Comment: now it is work.... it was must change element order of content ....the number is 2 Not 20
>>>thanks